# creating address of a customer using magento soap api in android

Tags: android, magento-1.4, android-ksoap2

In my App, create a customer using **customerCustomerCreate**  API, and getting the customer id. Now my requirement is to create the address of the customer, for that i am calling the customerAddressCreate api. but somehow i am not able to create the customer address. I

Tried with the code below:

```
                try {

                    SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    env.dotNet = false;
                    env.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
                    env.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;

                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "login");
                    request.addProperty("username", "user");
                    request.addProperty("apiKey", "apikey");
                    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);

                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                    Object result = env.getResponse();
                    Log.e("sessionId", result.toString());

                    String sessionId = result.toString();
       request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerAddressCreate");
                request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
                request.addProperty("customerId",custId);

                SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerAddressEntityCreate");
                customerEntity.addProperty("city", "bangalore");
                customerEntity.addProperty("company", "outthinking");
                customerEntity.addProperty("country_id", "01");
                customerEntity.addProperty("fax", "08012345");
                customerEntity.addProperty("firstname", "amit");
                customerEntity.addProperty("lastname", "chandra");
                customerEntity.addProperty("middlename", "raj");
                customerEntity.addProperty("postcode", "560007");
                customerEntity.addProperty("prefix", "a");
                customerEntity.addProperty("region_id", 03);
                customerEntity.addProperty("region", "karnataka");
             customerEntity.addProperty("street",Arrays.toString(myStrings));
                customerEntity.addProperty("suffix", "ac");
                customerEntity.addProperty("telephone", "+91-9962025341");
                customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_billing", false);
                customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_shipping", false);

                request.addProperty("addressdata", customerEntity);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

where myStrings is array of string of street. But i am getting the following error:

```
    SoapFault - faultcode: '100' faultstring: 'Please enter the first name.
    Please enter the last name.
    Please enter the street.
    Please enter the city.
    Please enter the telephone number.
    Please enter the zip/postal code.
    Please enter the country.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

What is wrong with my code? Provide  solution for this?

Comment: Hi @Amit Chandra did you found any solution am also facing same problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution. If any body still facing the problem, then please try with this code. it worked for me.

```
 request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "customerAddressCreate");
                    request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
                    //int customerId = Integer.parseInt(custId);
                    request.addProperty("customerId","custId");

                    SoapObject customerEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,              "customerAddressEntityCreate");

                    customerEntity.addProperty("city", "city");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("company","");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("country_id", "IN");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("fax", "");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("firstname", fname);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("lastname", lName);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("middlename", "");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("postcode", zipCode);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("prefix", "");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("region_id",1);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("region", region);

                    SoapObject streetEntity = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "street");


                    streetEntity.addProperty("street", street1);
                    //streetEntity.addProperty("street", street2);

                    customerEntity.addProperty("street",streetEntity);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("suffix", "");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("telephone", "8147555522");
                    customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_billing", true);
                    customerEntity.addProperty("is_default_shipping", false);

                    request.addProperty("addressData", customerEntity);



                    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
                    result = env.getResponse();
```

All you have to do is just change the name "addressdata" to addressData.